# Slerp Parent to face camera with child facing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to get my Parent to rotate itself so that the selected child will face my camera.

I have tried the script below, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

```
 IEnumerator lerpR(Transform child)
{
    while (Vector3.Distance(rotation.eulerAngles, child.forward) > .1f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotation.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(child.forward),0.1f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
    }
}
```

The IEnumerator is called by a rayCast that gets the child parameter